# C++ compile with libraries

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am working in an applpication in c++ in Linux, basically what I want to do is this, I have two .cpp files one of them is main.cpp which use threads. My problem is that I tried to make an executable like this: 
 `g++ -c main.cpp -> I get main.o
  g++ -c second.cpp -> I get second.o
  g++ -o executable main.o second.o`-> I get : 2ficheros.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `pthread_create'

SO I guess that my mistake is because I have to associate the pthread library in same way but I do not have idea how to do it. I was looking on internet and I find that I have to do something like this : `g++ -o executable main.o second.o pthread.o` but I do not know if it is correct and I cannot see the pthread.o just the pthread.h.

Sorry if I am speaking without knowledges, if someone can help me please.

Comment: `g++ -o executable main.cpp second.cpp -pthread`

Comment: Use `-pthread` option in all above commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link pthreads support:

```
c++ main.o second.o -o executable -pthread
```

Yes, without `-l`.  For other libraries (the math library for example) use this:

```
c++ main.o second.o -o executable -pthread -lm
```

And if you have another 3rd party library in some other directory:

```
c++ main.o second.o -o executable -pthread -L/opt/coolmolib -lcoolmolib
```

Note I am not using "g++" directly but a symbolic link, `c++`. On some systems this might be clang (to install clang on debian `apt install clang`).